How is this calculation of solution to damped oscillator done in MIT OCW "Vibrations and Waves" course?
I'm taking a course from MIT OCW called "8.03 - Vibrations and Waves". The first two lectures are reviewing simple harmonic motion and damped free oscillators.
In lecture 2 there is a derivation that I thought I knew completely but apparently not.
In what follows I show the derivation presented in the lecture and towards the end my question arises.
The full calculations are also present in the Notes for the lecture.
We have a rigid rod with uniform mass distribution hanging at one end so that it swings like a pendulum.

The lecturer introduces a "drag force" by defining
$$\tau_{drag}(t)=-b\dot{\theta}(t)$$
This is a torque.
Then, to obtain an equation of motion, he uses $\vec{\tau}=I\vec{\alpha}=I\ddot{\theta}$
$$\ddot{\theta}=\frac{\tau_{total}}{I}=\frac{\tau+\tau_{drag}}{I}$$
$$=\frac{-mg\frac{l}{2}\sin{\theta}-b\dot{\theta}}{\frac{ml^2}{3}}$$
$$\approx -\frac{3g}{2l}\theta-\frac{3b}{ml^2}\dot{\theta}$$
He then defines
$$\omega_0^2=\frac{3g}{2l}$$
$$\Gamma=\frac{3b}{ml^2}$$
to obtain the differential equation
$$\ddot{\theta}+\Gamma\dot{\theta}+\omega_0^2\theta=0$$
Next, we try a solution $\theta=\text{Re}(z(t))=\text{Re}(e^{i\alpha t})$, which gives us
$$\ddot{z}+\Gamma\dot{z}+\omega_0^2 z=0$$
$$e^{i\alpha t}(-\alpha^2+\Gamma\alpha i+\omega_0^2)=0$$
$$=e^{i\alpha t}p(i\alpha)=0$$
where $p(s)=s^2+\Gamma s+\omega_0^2$ is the characteristic polynomial of the differential equation.
Thus, we must have $p(i\alpha)=0$.
We find
$$\alpha=\frac{i\Gamma}{2}\pm \sqrt{\omega_0^2-\frac{\Gamma^2}{4}}\tag{1}$$
Everything is fine up to this point.
The lecturer then considers the case in which $\omega_0^2>\frac{\Gamma^2}{4}$.
The square root in (1) is real. Define
$$\omega^2=\omega_0^2-\frac{\Gamma^2}{4}\tag{2}$$
so that the two roots are
$$\alpha_1,\alpha_2=\frac{i\Gamma}{2}\pm\omega\tag{3}$$
At this point my question arises.
I would expect that the two complex solutions would be
$$z_1(t)=e^{-\frac{\Gamma it}{2}}e^{\frac{t\sqrt{\Gamma^2-4\omega_0^2}}{2}}$$
$$=e^{-\frac{\Gamma it}{2}}e^{i\omega t}$$
$$z_2(t)=e^{-\frac{\Gamma it}{2}}e^{-\frac{t\sqrt{\Gamma^2-4\omega_0^2}}{2}}$$
$$=e^{-\frac{\Gamma it}{2}}e^{-i\omega t}$$
This seems weird and I guess I am making a mistake somewhere. However, I don't understand the calculation made by the lecturer.
The lecturer obtains the complex solutions
$$z_1(t)=e^{\left ( i\omega-\frac{\Gamma}{2} \right )t}\tag{8}$$
$$z_1(t)=e^{\left ( -i\omega-\frac{\Gamma}{2} \right )t}\tag{9}$$
and the real solutions
$$\theta_1(t)=e^{-\frac{\Gamma}{2}t}\cos{\omega t}\tag{10}$$
$$\theta_2(t)=e^{-\frac{\Gamma}{2}t}\sin{\omega t}\tag{11}$$
My question is how did the lecturer go from the roots in (3) to the solutions in (8) and (9)?
What happened to the $i$ factor multiplying $t\frac{\Gamma}{2}$?
Finally, let me just show a screenshot of the calculations as they appear in the notes and the lecture


The trial solution was $z(t)=e^{i\alpha t}$, so $\alpha=i\Gamma/2\pm \omega$ yields $i\alpha=-\Gamma/2\pm i\omega t$. So there is no $i$ with the $\Gamma$ and you get a real exponential factor $e^{-\Gamma t/2}$ in both complex solutions.

There is a very silly oversight in the OP that was pointed out by user Semiclassical. Let me show what that oversight was.
We posited a trial solution $z(t)=e^{i\alpha t}$.
We found two roots
$$\alpha=\frac{i\Gamma}{2}\pm\omega$$
The two solutions are thus
$$z(t)=e^{t\left ( -\frac{\Gamma}{2}\pm\omega i \right )}$$
The real and imaginary parts of each solution yield a real solution.
Take one of the solutions: $z_1(t)=e^{t\left (-\frac{\Gamma}{2}+\omega i \right )}$.
The real and imaginary parts yield
$$\theta_1(t)=e^{-\frac{\Gamma}{2}}\cos{\omega t}$$
$$\theta_2(t)=e^{-\frac{\Gamma}{2}}\sin{\omega t}$$
Note that the second complex solution $z_1(t)=e^{t\left (-\frac{\Gamma}{2}-\omega i \right )}$ yields the solutions
$$\theta_3(t)=e^{-\frac{\Gamma}{2}}\cos{-\omega t}=\theta_1(t)$$
$$\theta_2(t)=e^{-\frac{\Gamma}{2}}\sin{(-\omega t)}=-\theta_2(t)$$
Thus, whether we use one or the other of the complex solutions we get the same basis of solutions.
